# asp.net hosting - forms authentication not working for .htm files

Tags: asp.net, hosting, forms-authentication

I've put a password around a website for preview purposes - it has .htm files generated by a content management system and .aspx files.

On my pc the Forms authentication restricts the .htm - but deployed live it does not - only the aspx files are restricted.

I realise that it maybe something specific to my hosting package (pipe10) but can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Thanks,

Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I just had to rename all the .HTML files to .ASPX - my hosting unfortunately didn't allow me to configure IIS.

Answer (score 1):

Probably `.htm` files are served directly by IIS and never pass through the ASP.NET pipeline to verify authentication. This is a common problem with IIS 6. You might need to [configure IIS](http://geekswithblogs.net/SanjayU/archive/2009/04/17/using-forms-authentication-with-html-pages-or-really-any-file-type.aspx) to associate the `.htm` extension with the `aspnet_isapi` filter.